# Antlr3.runtime access denied issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and on my first project, I stuck up in an access denied error.

I have an access denied error when I try to run the MVC application created by previous developer. It is my first day at work and - is kind of not cool. The error said "Antlr3.runtime access denied issue"

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your account may not have permission on some directories. If you are working in a windows environment, try giving your account full access to the "Temporary Asp.Net files" which is under c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework.

You need to also check in each version of the Framework folder for that temp asp.net files.

Comment: I tried that and still have the same error. Is there any thing else I need?

Comment: sorry but you need to give permission to the "temporary asp.net files" folder which is also in c:\users\...\AppData\Local\

Comment: That saves my day.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I deleted the temp folder. After that I executed in admin mode in Powershell the command iisreset and now it works fine.